# Use of undeclared type tableViewCell Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6.1

Can someone tell me what am I missing or doing wrong?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell! {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("chatCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as
      tableViewCell

    cell.chatText.text = object.valueForKey("chatText") as String
    cell.chatText.numberOfLines = 0
    let score = object.valueForKey("count") as Int
    cell.count.text = "\(score)"
    cell.time.text = "\((indexPath.row + 1) * 3)m ago"
    cell.replies.text = "\((indexPath.row + 1) * 1) replies"
    return cell
}
```

The error occurs on the tableViewCell and i been on this for hours but cant figure out whats wrong.

Comment: tableViewCell isn't a type unless you've created it yourself... Should probably be UITableViewCell

Comment: Yeah I tried that first but got the same error. Being new to this thats what got me confused.

Comment: I have a tableviewcell file called 'VoteTableViewCell' and put that in and it got rid of the previous errors but now have one on the return cell which says is not convertible to 'PFTableViewCell'

Comment: Oh, I see. You're using a custom cell. Make sure it's a custom PFTableViewCell and not a custom UITableViewCell since your cellForRowAtIndexPath method returns a PFTableViewCell.

Comment: That was it some how I missed that. Thank you.

Comment: Just so you know, that's not what caused your error. The error was caused because tableViewCell is not an inherent type... But glad you figured it out...

Comment: i vote that @LyndseyScott puts her comments in the answers section so that we may upvote :)

Comment: Agree you should so we can vote.

Comment: @LouisTur OK, done. I think I was just being lazy... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is caused by the fact that `tableViewCell` is neither an inherent type, nor a type that you've created. Instead of `tableViewCell`, you probably meant to use `UITableViewCell`, `PFTableViewCell`, or a custom class's cell. But from the error it seems as if `tableViewCell` has never been declared as a type.

From your comments underneath the question, it's clear that you are in fact using a custom cell named `VoteTableViewCell`. Therefore you should initialize `cell` as a `VoteTableViewCell`; but make sure it's a custom `PFTableViewCell` and not a custom `UITableViewCell` since your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method returns a `PFTableViewCell`.